# How do I expand the menu depending on the path in react ant design?

Tags: reactjs, antd, expansion

I have a code like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Menu } from 'antd'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
const { SubMenu } = Menu

const MenuC = () => {
  let location = useLocation()
  let [openKeys, setOpenKeys] = useState(['account'])

  let onOpenChange = (keys) => {
    // 
    const latestOpenKey = keys.find(key => openKeys.indexOf(key) === -1)
    setOpenKeys(latestOpenKey ? [latestOpenKey] : [])
  }

  return (
    <div className="nav">
      <div className="block">
        <div className="block-title">
          Menu
        </div>
        <div className="block-content">
          <Menu mode="inline"
            openKeys={openKeys}
            onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
            selectedKeys={[ location.pathname ]}
          >
            <SubMenu key="account" title="Account">
              <Menu.Item key="/profile">
                <NavLink to="/profile">My profile</NavLink>
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item key="/editprofile">
                <NavLink to="/editprofile">Edit profile</NavLink>
              </Menu.Item>
            </SubMenu>
            <SubMenu key="refs" title="Referrals">
              <Menu.Item key="/refs">
                <NavLink to="/refs">My referrals</NavLink>
              </Menu.Item>
            </SubMenu>
          </Menu>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MenuC
```

Menu items are highlighted normally, but submenus are not activated. I thought about checking the pathname, but it is very difficult.
What's the easiest way to implement submenu expansion?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger use effect on location change to check the pathname changes and set open keys value in a state variable

```
useEffect(() => {
    setOpenKeys(location.pathname === '/refs' ? ['refs'] : ['account'])
}, [location])
```